# Heroku maven spring boot Build success Run Failed

Tags: spring, maven, heroku, spring-boot

I wanted to deploy a spring boot project in heroku. The deployment is a success as its build triggered and build succeeded. Then i added procfile to run it.here's my procfile :

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar
```

and my pom.xml is:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>palebluedotstardust</groupId>
      <artifactId>BloodDB</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>

      <name>BloodDB</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

             <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


                <org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>
                <javax.servlet-api.version>2.5</javax.servlet-api.version>
                <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>

                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                <!--<commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>-->


          </properties>



            <pluginRepositories>
              <pluginRepository>
                  <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                  <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
              </pluginRepository>
              <pluginRepository>
                  <id>spring-milestones</id>
                  <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
              </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>


          <repositories>

...........
```

This is the log:

```
2017-03-16T05:04:02.185944+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=16048 -jar target/*.jar`
2017-03-16T05:04:04.368304+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-03-16T05:04:04.369353+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/*.jar
2017-03-16T05:04:04.469613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-16T05:04:04.456272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: Does the JAR in the `target/` dir exist locally when you run `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Also, try running `heroku run bash` and inspect the target dir with `ls target/`.

Comment: this is ls target output: 

BloodDB-1.0.0  BloodDB-1.0.0.war  BloodDB-1.0.0.war.original  classes  generated-sources  maven-archiver  maven-status mvn-dependency-list.log

Answer (score 0):

Your packaging says `<packaging>war</packaging>` so you dont have a jar file to execute.

here is the documentations on how to deploy war artifacts

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment